# expo-application nativeAppVersion return incorrect version

Tags: react-native, expo

Expo expo-application package return a wrong version in compare to what is set in app.json config file.

The expected version is 1.44.xx and the returned value is for some unknown reason 2.28.xx
This happen for both constant options -

```
Application.nativeAppVersion
```

and

```
Application.nativeBuildVersion
```

I considered alternatives.
I use expo managed so react-native-device-info is not an option and expo-constants is deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably running the app inside Expo Go and it is returning the version of the Expo Go app. It will return the correct one once you build the app.

If you want to get the correct version regardless of if you are running the app in Expo Go or not, try using something like this:

```js
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import * as Application from 'expo-application';

const getVersion = () => {
  if (Constants.appOwnership === 'expo') {
    return require('../package.json').version;
  }
  return Application.nativeApplicationVersion;
};
```